# Having trouble with JS code in my Github pages site, buttons not working

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML document as follows:

```js
desusifyValue = 0;

function desusify() {
  if (desusifyValue == 1) {
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Incremental Adventure";
    desusifyValue = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Art Project";
    desusifyValue = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onlick="desusify()">Desusify Title</button>
```

But when I click the button, the title doesn't change. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: First of all you a have typo here. There should be a ```onclick``` attribute, while you have a ```onlick``` in the button :)

Comment: Not just a typo. Your code changes the title to "Art Project" and sets desusify to 1. As soon as it is set to 1, the `if` statement runs and the title is re-changed to "Incrimental Adventure".

Answer (score 1):

`<button onlick="desusify()">Desusify Title</button>`

should be

`<button onclick="desusify()">Desusify Title</button>`

onlick --> onclick

Answer (score 1):

1. It should be `onclick` and not `onlick` .

```
<button onclick="desusify()">Desusify Title</button>
```

2. This

```
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Art Project";
```

should be

```
window.document.title = "Art Project";
```

---

```js
desusifyValue = 0;

function desusify() {
  if (desusifyValue == 1) {
    window.document.title = "Incremental Adventure";
    desusifyValue = 0;
  } else {
    window.document.title = "Art Project";
    desusifyValue = 1;
  }
}
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Art Project";
```

```html
<button onclick="desusify()">Desusify Title</button>
```

---

Also at the place of `desusifyValue = 0;` try using  `let desusifyValue = 0;`. Note only on the first one.

Answer (score 0):

For your task, the window object has a window.document.title property. You can change it like this

```
window.document.title = "Art Project";
```

Comment: Thank you! I will probably use this to declutter my other projects.